# Calculate distance from a lat/lon coord to a street

Tags: ios, math, geolocation

I have the coordinates for a street, for example:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D street[3];
street[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-17.3521, 145.5898);
street[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-17.3518, 145.5910);
street[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-17.3515, 145.5917);
```

And a location that is fairly close to the street (about 60 meters):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-17.3525, 145.5911);
```

How can I calculate the distance between the location and position along the street's path?

I'm not looking for the distance to the closest point in the array, I want the distance to the closest position in between the points.

***EDIT***

It's easier to describe my question with a picture:

[image: whats going on]

- `street` is the three red dots
- `location` is the blue dot

I want to calculate the length of the yellow line in meters.

Comment: You can only find the crow distance i.e displacement

Comment: To find the actual road distance you have to find the coords in straight line

Comment: I'm not clear on what exactly you're trying to calculate- are you wanting to find the distance between your point adjacent to the street and the point that falls on the road (line created by the three street points) closest to that adjacent point?

Comment: @blabus yes, I want the distance from `location` to the line created by the three points in `street`.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

Comment: You can use regular cartesian distances if the points are close enough. The earth's curvature will make a difference as the distance increases between the various points of interest. If this is a concern, you should consider using the Cross-Track distance formulation at http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: @andand in my case, distances will never be greater than 50 meters and the iOS GPS equipment is not accurate enough anyway to get perfect measurements. The search is happening repeatedly and the full database is every street worldwide, so I'm already doing a rough distance calculation to find only the three or four streets that are within about 50 meters, and then I just need to figure out which of those is the closest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt to solve this, but I'm not sure if it's the best way?

```
// http://www.cprogramto.com/c-program-to-find-shortest-distance-between-point-and-line-segment/
double FindDistanceToSegment(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double pointX, double pointY)
{
  double diffX = x2 - x1;
  float diffY = y2 - y1;
  if ((diffX == 0) && (diffY == 0))
  {
    diffX = pointX - x1;
    diffY = pointY - y1;
    return sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY);
  }

  float t = ((pointX - x1) * diffX + (pointY - y1) * diffY) / (diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY);

  if (t < 0)
  {
    //point is nearest to the first point i.e x1 and y1
    diffX = pointX - x1;
    diffY = pointY - y1;
  }
  else if (t > 1)
  {
    //point is nearest to the end point i.e x2 and y2
    diffX = pointX - x2;
    diffY = pointY - y2;
  }
  else
  {
    //if perpendicular line intersect the line segment.
    diffX = pointX - (x1 + t * diffX);
    diffY = pointY - (y1 + t * diffY);
  }

  //returning shortest distance
  return sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY);
}
```

-

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D street[3];
street[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-17.3521, 145.5898);
street[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-17.3518, 145.5910);
street[2] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-17.3515, 145.5917);

CLLocationCoordinate2D location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-17.3525, 145.5911);


CLLocationDegrees distanceDegrees = CGFLOAT_MAX;
for (NSUInteger nodeIndex = 1; nodeIndex < 3; nodeIndex++) {
  CLLocationCoordinate2D nodeCoord = street[nodeIndex];
  CLLocationCoordinate2D prevNodeCoord = street[nodeIndex - 1];

  CLLocationDegrees distanceToCurrent = FindDistanceToSegment(prevNodeCoord.longitude, prevNodeCoord.latitude, nodeCoord.longitude, nodeCoord.latitude, location.longitude, location.latitude);

  if (distanceToCurrent < distanceDegrees)
    distanceDegrees = distanceToCurrent;
}

CLLocationDistance distance = distanceDegrees * 111111; // 1.0 degree is approximately 111,111 meters

NSLog(@"%f", distance);  // 78.15 meters
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this site: [link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

It shows different types of distance measuring with latitude and longitude coordinates and even some code examples (in javascript).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the find the crow distance between two locations, make `CLLocation` object of two coords, then

```
CLLocationDistance meters = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];
```

and if you have find the actual road distance divide the two coords to several coords in straight line and find the distance and add them up.

Comment: I don't have two locations, I have four locations. I want to calculate the distance from `location` to the closest position somewhere in between `street[0]` and `street[1]`.

Comment: So, you have to calculate the distance from `location` to every `street` location and calculate them all, to find the closest position. You can't find without knowing the distance between them.

Comment: except I need the closest point along the path, which probably is not one of the points in the array. It will be something in between. See my edited question with a fancy picture.